# Vue.js v-if conditional not properly work in v-for loop. Why?

Tags: vue.js, conditional-statements

This is stupid question, but i am still beating on it a few hours..

Simple Repro:

```
 **https://codepen.io/sergio1c/pen/eYZRQJW**
```

Could anyone answer to me, why the text 'Step_2 text' is shown when the particaular conditional on template level is false? What am missing?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: it is because when you are showing Step_{{n}} and when it finishes looping the value of n is 2 and it show step_2 instead of step_1

Comment: @NaveenKashyap yes, but the model variable step = 1, and the condition
     <template v-if="step == 2">     is false, therefore it should not shown. Right?

Comment: My bad..updated explanation in aswer...

Answer (score 0):

It because I've wrote not right logic in my conditional expression. In this case it have to be as: `n == step && step == 1` where 1 is current step on form (stepper)